# Power BI Icon Library

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I repeatedly get tasked to create architecture diagrams for the workflow and flow of data when publishing reports from Power BI Desktop to PowerBI.com. I often have to create diagrams showing how Power BI Embedded works and the architecture mirroring work spaces. I have been resorting to zooming in on PowerBI.com to take screen shots for icons like Workspaces, Apps, Reports, Datasets, Dataflows, Dashboards, Row-Level Security, etc... Wondering if anyone has a library of these icons I could use? A library of icons for Power Apps and Power Automate would be helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm pretty sure that asking for an icon pack to do diagrams is rather off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: http://pbiux.azurewebsites.net/ gets you some of the way

Comment: You could use the font file that provides the glyphs from powerbi.com.